# calling a javascript function in another javascript function several times

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I had a javascript function and it works well:

```
function playMp3(str) {
  ...
}
```

the other script:

```
function playMp3wholepage() {
  var dgs=new Array();
  dgs[0] = "/abc.mp3";
  dgs[1] = "/dac.mp3";
  dgs[2] = "/hf.mp3";
  ....
  dgs[28] = "/er23.mp3";
  dgs[29] = "/read/34_15.mp3";
  for (i=0;i<=29;i++){
    ses = dgs[i]
    setTimeout("playMp3(ses);", 2000)
  }
}
```

I want to play all of the sounds in the order that given in second script. but I could not get the second script run, it just play the last sound (dgs[29]), not all of them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setTimeout callback execute, `sec` is already `dgs[29]`, you need to create another function scope to perserve the value.

```
for (var i=0; i<=dgs.length; i++){
   (function (i) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           playMp3(dgs[i]);
       }, 2000 * i);
   }(i));
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, pass `dgs[i]` into the function instead of `i` (since the array only holds strings and then you don't need to worry about changes made to the array before some or all of the timeouts run).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what's happening is that your loop completes so fast, that all calls to `playMp3` are being called essentially at once. However, the last call to `setTimeout` would have set the last sound to play, and that's why it's all you hear.

Furthermore, use the length or your array, and make your code flexible:

```
for(var i=0; i<dgs.length; i++) {      
}
```

Comment: You're right that the timeout delay needs to be multiplied by the loop counter, but at the point later when the timeouts actually start executing they all reference the same `ses` variable which will be set to whatever it was at the end of the for loop (i.e., the last item).

Comment: You're right, thanks. I removed that section as there are already answers here to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

This is something about closure. You can learn more [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

```
function playMp3wholepage() {
   var dgs=new Array();
   dgs[0] = "/abc.mp3";
   dgs[1] = "/dac.mp3";
   dgs[2] = "/hf.mp3";
   for (i=0;i<dgs.length;i++){
       ses = dgs[i];
       (function(mp3) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               playMp3(mp3);
           }, 2000);
       })(ses);
   }
}
```